# Check-in-policy for writing Comment for atleast 1 public method or class before checin to TFS

Tags: c#, asp.net, version-control, tfs

Do anybody know if it is posible to write Checkin-In-Policy that not allow user to checkin his code if he has not written atleast one comment to his class's any public method or class itself.

Following are few helpful links

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163320.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the [**TFS Code Comment Checkin Policy**](http://tfsccpolicy.codeplex.com/)

Comment: this looks nice, i am trying this

Answer (score 1):

I've written a policy that is more granular and also works with VS 2012:

[cdcp.codeplex.com](http://cdcp.codeplex.com)

Comment: nice, do we have option to force user to write at least one comment no matter its on class or methods?

Comment: I'm currently fighting against the buggy roslyn compiler. When the roslyn compiler is RTM I'll think about implementing more features.